# Install dotnet 1.1 over 4

Tags: .net, installation, downgrade

Does installing Dotnet 1.1 after 4.0 give any head aches?

--

I have a machine with Dotnet 2, 3.5 and 4.0.
Now there is a need to install Dotnet 1.1 too.

Are there any steps I should do before?  Will the installation hate and haunt me?  Will all run smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried installing 1.0 and 1.1 after 2/3.5/4 now.  And everything seems to work normally.

Update: 1.0 and 1.1 where not installed even though c:\windows... had the frameworks in it.  I tried to run a 1.1 application and it complained.  I installed 1.1 and the application worked.  (so I "know" it wasn't installed beforehand)
Now I will run for a while before I can say that installing 1.1 after 2/3.5/4 will work.

Comment: This was a long time ago and I cannot explicitly remember it working properly. On the other hand I cannot remember it failing either (whatever "it" was, too many systems have run under the bridge since then); so I guess it works.

Answer (score 3):

.NET 1.1, .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 can all be installed side-by-side.

You might run into oddness in the following areas:

1. The 1.1 installer might be broken and fail to allow this.
2. It might break (e.g.) your ASP.NET installation.
3. Up to this point, installed applications targeted against .NET 1.1 will have been using .NET 2.0 or .NET 4.0. Once you install 1.1, they might start using the correct (old) version. It might be subtly different from the newer versions.

Comment: I suppose the 1.1 installer doesn't crash 2/3.5/4 then.  Just that the references in the applications might get messy.  Or is this even true? I didn't know there was a way to target "latest framework".  I believed if you reference a dotnet2 DLL/assembly, an application will never retarget to a 1.1 DLL/assembly?